# How to configure SVN to show a collection of repositories

Tags: apache, svn, apache2, webdav

I want to show a collection of all repositories using mod_authz_svn. When I access it, I get a 403 error (forbidden).

I found out it works fine, when not specifying `AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.authz`, and I am seeing all my repositories, but permissions (of course) don't work anymore.

Is it even possible to show a collection of repositories while using `AuthzSVNAccessFile`?

This is my **dav_svn.authz**:

```
[groups]
admin = me
users = you,others

[/]
* = r
@admin = rw

[repo:/subfolder]
@users = rw
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me.

On my Ubuntu 14.04 server, I added the following line to **/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf**
`SVNListParentPath  on`

Be sure to restart Apache:
`$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

I created an index.html showing a list of all of my repo, each name on the list is a name to repository itself.

Comment: Does that allow you to browse the actual repository to see the various files and branches and such of the source tree? I really don't see how that would do anything more than allowing you to see the Linux directory structure created by Subversion which does not reflect the actual source code tree structure stored by Subversion.

Comment: @RichardChambers  [mod_dav_svn](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.mod_dav_svn.conf.html) must be enabled on apache